# How to find standard errors for correlations between linked individuals in a social network?

Tags: regression, social-network

I have data on an entire social network of individuals. I'd like to know whether a particular individual-level characteristic is more similar among individuals who are directly linked than among random pairs. (For now I'm not worried by the direction of causality: the correlation could reflect homophily or social influence.) The comparison isn't hard, but given that cases are non-independent by hypothesis - everybody is linked in a single network - what's the best way of constructing standard errors?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Respondent Driven Sampling](http://www.respondentdrivensampling.org)? The answer to your question is a central component of this sampling method. [Salganik](http://www.princeton.edu/~mjs3/) has written a number of helpful topics on this subject. The RDS literature addresses the topic of standard errors for homophily in a sample.

Comment: That looks interesting, but I have the whole network. My problem is not that I may have oversampled popular individuals, but that people who are friends may be non-independent and I need to adjust standard errors for that